# SQL - Latest record based on time-stamp and ID

Tags: sql

Changing my whole question as I get a lot of complaints about posting images. I also added a code which is more similar to my situation. My apologies I am new to SO, I try and make it as easy as possible for you.

I use IBM DB2 DBMS

I have a query which selects a lot of records(messages) that always have an ID(which is supposed to be unique), a status(error, completed) and a time-stamp. My query is the following;

```
select *
 from  tableone tr, tabletwo ms
 where ms.TS BETWEEN '2017-09-15 00:00:00.000' and '2017-09-16 00:00:00.000'
 and ms.ID=tr.ID
 and ms.STATUS in ('ERROR','COMPLETED')
 ORDER by tr.ID
```

The ID is unique to one message, a message can get multiple statuses on different time-stamps, which will result in multiple records as output of the query above.

I wish to only have records with unique messages and the latest gotten status.

I hope you guys and gals can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Syntax error. Remove that comma before WHERE.

Comment: Does your dbms really accept 1 as table alias? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to use numbers as aliases...

Comment: Do not use numbers as identifiers...

Comment: It is just an example, I use TR and MS (Transactions and Messages) as alias. Comma is a typo. I don't know how to put a table in the question. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yea but I didn't upload code, just the output in excel :D

Comment: I use IBM DB2 DBMS

Answer (score 1):

Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server:

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by t1.ID order by t1.Timestamp desc) rn
from MyTable t1
where t1.STATUS in ('ERROR','COMPLETED')
)
select *
from CTE
where rn = 1
```

MySQL

```
select t1.*
from MyTable t1
inner join
(
select t2.ID, max(t2.Timestamp) as MaxT
from MyTable t2
where t2.STATUS in ('ERROR','COMPLETED')
group by t2.ID
) x3
on x3.ID = t1.ID
and x3.MaxT = t1.Timestamp
where t1.STATUS in ('ERROR','COMPLETED')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
select *
 from  table_name a,
 where a.STATUS in ('ERROR','COMPLETED')
 and a.TimeStamp = (select max(b.TimeStamp)
                     from  table_name b,
                     where a.ID=B.ID) 
 ORDER by a.ID
```

or

```
select *
 from  table_name a,
 where a.STATUS in ('ERROR','COMPLETED')
 and a.TimeStamp = (select Top(1) b.TimeStamp
                     from  table_name b,
                     where a.ID=B.ID
                     order by b.TimeStamp desc) 
 ORDER by a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code based on your values.

I Reversed your ID to get only numbers. I did a row_number by the new ID and sorting it desc to get the newest.

**With pretty ID:**

```
select * from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by TrueID order by timestamp DESC) as RN 
from (
SELECT REVERSE(substring(reverse([ID]),1,2)) as TrueID
  ,[Status]
  ,[Timestamp]
 FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[statustable])x
 )z where RN= 1
```

**With original ID:**

```
select * from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by timestamp DESC) as RN 
from (
SELECT ID
  ,[Status]
  ,[Timestamp]
FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[statustable])x
)z where RN= 1
```